# var_dump for DOMNodeList printout unexpected result

Tags: php, xml, var-dump

I have a xml file I load it as the following:

```
//$file the file system path of the xml file
function getTopicsList($file){
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load( $file );
        var_dump($doc->getElementsByTagName('topic'));
        return $doc->getElementsByTagName('topic');
    }
```

The loaded xml file contents is something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topics>
    <topic>
        <title>Title1</title>
        <keywords>"Some Keys"</keywords>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <title>The Title</title>
        <keywords>Another Key</keywords>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <title>A Title</title>
        <keywords>Key two</keywords>
    </topic>
</topics>
```

The `var_dump()` in the above code just printout limited information such as:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#30 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

I expected that it should print at least the properties of that object i.e the xml tags and its values. I tried to use other functions such as `print_r()` and `var_export()` but there is no details I want.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is node list. You can iterate it with `foreach` or access nodes using the `item()` method.

Node lists are used at different places, `getElementsByTagName()` is one, another is the `$childNodes` property. Xpath expressions return node lists, too.

Be aware that the nodes can be not only elements but several node types. Like text, cdata section or attribute.

You can use var_dump() to dump a single node. This works with PHP >= 5.3.11 or >= 5.4.1.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<foo/>'); 
var_dump($dom->documentElement);
```

Output:

```
object(DOMElement)#2 (18) { 
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> 
  NULL 
  ["tagName"]=> 
  string(3) "foo" 
  ["textContent"]=> 
  string(0) "" 
  ["baseURI"]=> 
  string(1) "/" 
  ["localName"]=> 
  string(3) "foo" 
  ["prefix"]=> 
  string(0) "" 
  ["ownerDocument"]=> 
    ...
```